# The set $A= [z \in \mathbb C : |z+2|<2 $ or $ |z-2|<2]$ is not path connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

The set $A= [z \in \mathbb C : |z+2|<2$ or $|z-2|<2]$ is not path connected.

I supposed that $A$ is path connected. Then there is a path , a continuous function $\gamma (t)=f_1(t)+if_2(t)$.

After that assumption how could I arrive at a contradiction ?

Comment: Your set $A$ is the union of two open balls with radius $2$, one has center $2$, the other has center $-2$. If $\gamma$ is a path in $A$, what can you say about the preimages of the open balls?

Comment: yes, any further explanation please

Comment: Well, what can you say about the preimages of these disjoint open balls in the interval $\Bbb I$, the domain of $\gamma$. How does this relate to the connectedness of $\Bbb I$?

Comment: $\mathbb I$ is an union of two disjoint open intervals ? Am I correct ?

Comment: Well, $\Bbb I$ would then be a union of disjoint non-empty open sets if $\gamma$ meets both balls. But the interval is connected, so it cannot be written as such a union.

Comment: Therefore a contradiction !

Comment: Right, so there is no path connecting a point in one ball with a point in the other ball. Note that this is basically the same argument as in the proof that a path connected set is connected. $A$ is not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that $B(-2,2)$ and $B(2,2)$ are convex and so path connected, so
to show that $A$ is not path connected, you must show that there is no path
between the two sets.

Suppose $\gamma$ is such a path, that is $\gamma(0) \in B(-2,2), \gamma(1) \in B(2,2)$.

Look at $r(t)=\operatorname{re} \gamma(t)$. Note that $r(0) <0, r(1) >1$ so there
must be some $t$ such that $r(t) = 0$. However, the inaginary axis does not
intersect $A$ hence a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Intersecting the balls of radius slightly greater than the balls you have with your subspace implies that your subspace isn't connected (since you will have two disjoint open non-trivial sets which cover the space).

Now, not connected implies not path-connected.